# usando axios desde el action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux

Estoy usando *javascript*, *react*, *readux* y *axios*.

Resulta que desde el `action` estoy implementando un `post` con *axios*, y cuando la promesa devuelta por este se resuelve no me devuelve los valores que espero. Si lo hace cuando va por la rama de `catch`. Cabe aclarar que la promesa se resuelva tanto por el `.then` como por el `.catch` me devuelve los mismos valores, y eso es algo que no estoy esperando.

Dejo el codigo para que entiendan mi problema.

```
export const createuser = (payload) => {
    return async function (dispatch) {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3001/create-user', payload)
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log('RESOLV')
                return {
                    type: CREATE_USER,
                    payload:''
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                if (error.response)
                    return {
                       type: CREATE_USER,
                       payload: JSON.parse(error.config.data)
                    }
                
            })
        console.log('AACCAA',response)
        dispatch({
            type: response.type,
            payload: response.payload
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

se te olvidó llamar res.data en el payload cuando usas el then y por eso no te envía nada,en el catch si que te coge los datos porque en el payload estas cogiendo error.config.data,
te dejo el código por aqui:

```
export const createuser = (payload) => {
return async function (dispatch) {
    const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3001/create-user', payload)
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log('RESOLV')
            return {
                type: CREATE_USER,
                payload:res.data
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response)
                return {
                   type: CREATE_USER,
                   payload: JSON.parse(error.config.data)
                }
            
        })
    console.log('AACCAA',response)
    dispatch({
        type: response.type,
        payload: response.payload
    })
}}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda,un saludo!!!